# Threadpool execution stops at an arbitrary point in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

I am implementing my own generic Threadpool algorithm in C, using the fibonacci sequence for test purposes, and for the last few days I have been stuck with a problem that completely manages to baffle me.

When executing the program it will work until at some point it suddenly stops for no reason that is readily apparent for me.

The one thing I noticed is that the execution stops after some small amount of time, as it stops earlier in the execution if print commands or sleep commands are added to it.

EDIT: Missed this part, I already tested for Deadlocks and there are none, it seems to just not push any new things onto the stack at some point, leading to all threads just trying to pull from the stack, recognising it's empty and jumping back up just to repeat that process ad-infinitum.

Here is the code:

threadpool.h

```c
#ifndef THREADPOOL_H_INCLUDED
#define THREADPOOL_H_INCLUDED

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef void (*ThreadTask_f)(void*);

typedef struct Future {
    ThreadTask_f fn;   //Pointer to the to be executed function
    bool fulfilled;
} Future;


extern int tpInit(size_t size);

extern void tpRelease(void);

extern void tpAsync(Future *future);

extern void tpAwait(Future *future);

/* creates an abstraction for easy interaction of functions with the threadpool
 * TYPE: type that the function returns
 * NAME: name of the function to be parralelised
 * ARG: type of the argument of the function given
*/
#define TASK(TYPE, NAME, ARG) \
    TYPE NAME(ARG); \
    \
    typedef struct { \
        Future fut;  \
        ARG    arg;  \
        TYPE   res;  \
    } NAME ## _fut;  \
    \
    static void NAME ## Thunk(void *args) { \
        NAME ## _fut *data = args;          \
        data->res = NAME(data->arg);        \
    } \
    static inline NAME ## _fut NAME ## Future(ARG arg) { \
        return (NAME ## _fut) {                          \
            .fut = { .fn = &NAME ## Thunk, .fulfilled = false },             \
            .arg = arg                                   \
        };                                               \
    } \
    static inline NAME ## _fut* NAME ## Async(NAME ## _fut *future) { \
        tpAsync(&future->fut);                 \
        return future;                         \
    } \
    static inline TYPE NAME ## Await(NAME ## _fut *future) { \
        tpAwait(&future->fut);        \
        return future->res;           \
    }

#endif
```

threadpool.c

```c
#include "threadpool.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define THREADSTACKSIZE 8388608
#define INITSTACKSIZE 1024  //initial value for how many Tasks can be in the taskstack
#define STACKMEMMULT 2  //if the TaskStack is full, multiply by this


typedef struct TaskStack {
    Future **start;
    size_t size;
    long current;
} TaskStack;

typedef struct ThreadPool {
    size_t size;
    pthread_t *threads;
    TaskStack *stack;
} ThreadPool;

static pthread_mutex_t stackAccess;

static ThreadPool *tp;

void nsleep(unsigned long nano) {
    struct timespec delay = {
        .tv_sec = 0,
        .tv_nsec = nano
    };
    nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
}

static void push(Future *future){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stackAccess);
        if(tp->stack->current++==tp->stack->size){
            tp->stack->size*=2;
            tp->stack->start=realloc(tp->stack->start, tp->stack->size);
        }
        tp->stack->start[tp->stack->current]=future;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stackAccess);
}

static Future *pull(){
    Future *retVal=NULL;
    PULLBEGIN:
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stackAccess);
        if(tp->stack->current==-1){ //if there is nothing on the stack test if there is a cancel attempt and yield the scheduler to a thread that might add tasks.
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&stackAccess);
            pthread_testcancel();
            sched_yield();
            goto PULLBEGIN;
        }
        retVal=tp->stack->start[tp->stack->current];
        tp->stack->current--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stackAccess);
    return retVal;
}

static void *workerThread(void *args){
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);

    Future *fut;
    while(true){
        fut=pull();
        fut->fn(fut);
        fut->fulfilled=true;
        pthread_testcancel();
    }

    return NULL;
}

int tpInit(size_t size) {
    
    int err;
    tp=NULL;
    accessStack=0;
    pushExisting=0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&stackAccess, NULL);
    tp=malloc(sizeof(ThreadPool));
    if(tp==NULL){
        err=0;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->size=0;
    tp->stack=malloc(sizeof(TaskStack));
    if(tp->stack==NULL){
        err=1;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->threads=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*size);
    if(tp->threads==NULL){
        err=2;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->stack->start=malloc(sizeof(Future *)*INITSTACKSIZE);
    if(tp->stack->start==NULL){
        err=3;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->stack->current=-1;
    tp->stack->size=INITSTACKSIZE; 
    pthread_attr_t attributes;
    if(pthread_attr_init(&attributes)!=0){
        err=4;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    if(pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attributes, THREADSTACKSIZE)!=0){
        err=5;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }

    if(pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attributes, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE)!=0){
        err=6;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        if(pthread_create(&(tp->threads[i]), &attributes, workerThread,NULL)!=0){
            err=20+i;
            goto ERRHANDLINIT;
        }
    }
    return 0;

    ERRHANDLINIT:
    perror("Problem while initiating the threadpool with the following errcode: ");
    fprintf(stderr,"%i\n", err);
    return -1;
}

void tpRelease(void) {
    for(int i=0; i<tp->size; i++){
        pthread_cancel(tp->threads[i]);
        pthread_join(tp->threads[i], NULL);
    }
    free(tp->stack->start);
    free(tp->stack);
    free(tp->threads);
    free(tp);
}

void tpAsync(Future *future) {
    future->fulfilled=false;
    push(future);
    return;
}

void tpAwait(Future *future) {
    while(!future->fulfilled){
        Future *workFut=pull();
        workFut->fn(workFut);
        workFut->fulfilled=true;
    }
}
```

main.c

```c
#include "threadpool.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


static TASK(long, fib, long);

long fib(long n) {
    if (n <= 1){
        return n;
    }

    fib_fut *a = fibAsync((fib_fut[]) { fibFuture(n - 1) });
    fib_fut *b = fibAsync((fib_fut[]) { fibFuture(n - 2) });

    return fibAwait(a) + fibAwait(b);
}

int main() {
    if (tpInit(8) != 0)
        perror("Thread Pool initialization failed"), exit(-1);
    atexit(&tpRelease);
    
    for (long i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
        printf("fib(%2li) = %li\n", i, fib(i));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
#!/usr/bin/make
.SUFFIXES:
.PHONY: all run pack clean

SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
TAR = threadpool

CFLAGS = -std=gnu11 -c -g -Os -Wall -MMD -MP
LFLAGS = -pthread

DEP = $(OBJ:%.o=%.d)
-include $(DEP)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(TAR): $(filter-out quicksort.o,$(OBJ))
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

all: $(TAR)

run: all
    ./$(TAR)

clean:
    $(RM) $(RMFILES) $(OBJ) $(TAR) bench $(DEP) $(PCK)
```

I really hope you have some idea what is happening. Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be there is a deadlock. Find out at which line it stops. Run this program in gdb. You can also put multiple printfs in your code to figure out at which line it stops.

Comment: Already did that stuff, sorry for leaving it out, and it continually tries to pull from the stack, recognises that it is empty, and jumps at the top on all threads, even though it should be in the middle of calculating.

Comment: In `push`, you are doing `++pushExisting;` _outside_ of the critical section but do `--pushExisting;` _inside_. For starters, move the increment below the mutex lock call.

Comment: `sched_yield` can be problematic in its implementation. Consider using a short `nanosleep` instead

Comment: Ok thank you for both of that, pushExisting was merely an idea to have it prefer pushes to pulls, but I wrote it out so was merely an old remnant, removed it now.

And I'll try.

Comment: Tested it with nanosleep instead of sched_yield, and the same problem persists, though I will keep the nanosleep method because of the possibility of the mentioned bad implementations.

Comment: You have a _bug_: In `push`, change `realloc(tp->stack->start, tp->stack->size);` into `tp->stack->start = realloc(tp->stack->start, tp->stack->size);`

Comment: _Side note:_ Doing `realloc` _inside_ a mutex locked region may not be the best design choice for speed and realtime safety.

Comment: Oh god that is an embarassing mistake.
Never came up because didn't test it with a large enough dataset yet.

And hmm true regarding your side note, I'll be taking a second look (already have an idea how) once I get it running without stopping for an unknown reason.

Comment: You should use condition variables. If the stack is empty then that thread should go to sleep. When some thread pushes something on the stack then that thread should wake up other threads. This is a typucal producer-consumer problem. Please look here: http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/pthread_cond_init.html and here: http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/pthread_cond_init.html

Comment: Also, malloc(), realloc() can sleep, so you should not put these in your critical section.

Comment: Even with the fix, and doing `nanosleep`, you _still_ have a race condition. The numerous threads might prevent any new requests being added due to a livelock. This depends upon whether `pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock` implements _fair_ scheduling. At best, things might be sluggish. You may want to implement a ticket lock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock This is what I often use for my own code (implemented with `stdatomic.h` primitives)

Comment: Ok thank you for your recommendations.
In order to not spam the comments to much I will report back in form of a edit once I tried your solutions, this might take a moment as I am busy.
Amusingly I actually considered doing a ticket lock before (without knowing how it is called) but thought it would be unnecessary.

Comment: You're also accessing `fulfilled` _outside_ the locked region?

Comment: Yes, as it's a property of an individual future, not the stack, and each future can only be active in a single thread, because of the lock on pull. 
So once it's gone from the stack no other thread can access it.

Comment: Originally, I (re)invented the ticket lock on my own (without knowing what it was called, either) ;-) When you edit your question, you can send a comment specifically to me (so it shows up in my inbox) and I can take a look at it.

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you for your help, because of it I figured the problem out, look at my answer if you want for more details.

Comment: You really, *really* don't want to spin on `sched_yield` that way. There may be no thread to yield to, in which case you're spinning on acquiring and releasing a mutex, which can be disastrous for system-wide performance. If two threads do this at the same time, you can saturate inter-core busses and severely decrease the entire system's speed. What happens if a thread has nothing to yield to and shares a physical core with a thread doing the real work? Is a 50% performance penalty acceptable? If this is toy code, fine. But its design clearly does not care about the performance impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, with the gracious help of Craig Estey and Amit (which you can see in the comments under the original post).

So in the end it was a Deadlock, because, as you can still see in the original post which I will not modify so anyone interested has a chance to gaze upon my folly.

This happened because at one point there will be 6 threads waiting to pull, the stack is empty, and the two remaining threads is one going into await, and the other just having fulfilled it's given function, which is one that didn't call another recursively (in our example one with fib(0) or fib(1)). Now that that is finished the thread, let's call it thread 7, going into fib_await() will check if the value that it is waiting for is fulfilled, which at this point it isn't yet, thus it checks if there are any other in the stack. As there are none, it is stuck in wait.

Now the other thread, thread 8, the one that just fulfilled it's given function marks it's future as fulfilled and tries to pull another future. As it is empty, it too will stay in pull.

Now all threads are stuck in pull and none can progress as the one that is waiting on another would first have to leave pull().

My only modifications came for pull(), push(), tpAwait(), tpInit(), and workerThread() as I also implemented a very simple ticket lock.

threadpool.c

```c
static void ticketLockInit(){
    atomic_init(&nowServing, 0);
    atomic_init(&nextTicket, 0);
}

static inline void ticketLockAcquire(){

    atomic_long myTicket=atomic_fetch_add(&nextTicket,1);

    while(myTicket!=nowServing){
        nsleep(1);
    }

}

static inline void ticketLockRelease(){
    ++nowServing;
}

static void push(Future *future){
    
    ticketLockAcquire();
        if(++tp->stack->current==tp->stack->size){
            fprintf(stderr, "MemRealloc\n");
            tp->stack->size=tp->stack->size*2;
            tp->stack->start=realloc(tp->stack->start, tp->stack->size);
        }
        tp->stack->start[tp->stack->current]=future;
    ticketLockRelease();

}

static Future *pull(){
    Future *retVal=NULL;

    ticketLockAcquire();
        if(tp->stack->current>-1){  //if there is nothing on the stack test if there is a cancel attempt and yield the scheduler to a thread that might add tasks.
            retVal=tp->stack->start[tp->stack->current];
        tp->stack->current--;
        }
    ticketLockRelease();

    return retVal;
}

static void *workerThread(void *args){
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);

    Future *fut;
    while(true){
        if((fut=pull())!=NULL){
            fut->fn(fut);
            fut->fulfilled=true;
            pthread_testcancel();
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void tpAwait(Future *future) {
    while(!future->fulfilled){
        
        Future *workFut;
        if((workFut=pull())!=NULL){
            workFut->fn(workFut);
            workFut->fulfilled=true;
            pthread_testcancel();
        }
        
        
    }
}

int tpInit(size_t size) {
    
    int err;
    tp=NULL;
    accessStack=0;
    pushExisting=0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&stackAccess, NULL);
    ticketLockInit();
    tp=malloc(sizeof(ThreadPool));
    if(tp==NULL){
        err=0;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->size=0;
    tp->stack=malloc(sizeof(TaskStack));
    if(tp->stack==NULL){
        err=1;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->threads=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*size);
    if(tp->threads==NULL){
        err=2;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->stack->start=malloc(sizeof(Future *)*INITSTACKSIZE);
    if(tp->stack->start==NULL){
        err=3;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    tp->stack->current=-1;
    tp->stack->size=INITSTACKSIZE; 
    pthread_attr_t attributes;
    if(pthread_attr_init(&attributes)!=0){
        err=4;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }
    if(pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attributes, THREADSTACKSIZE)!=0){
        err=5;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }

    if(pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attributes, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE)!=0){
        err=6;
        goto ERRHANDLINIT;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        if(pthread_create(&(tp->threads[i]), &attributes, workerThread,NULL)!=0){
            err=20+i;
            goto ERRHANDLINIT;
        }
    }
    return 0;

    ERRHANDLINIT:
    perror("Problem while initiating the threadpool with the following errcode: ");
    fprintf(stderr,"%i\n", err);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I seem to be continually raining on the parade :-) Access to `nowServing` should use atomics. It may be working on x86 because of its tighter memory model and cache snooping and `nsleep` may force a cache flush. But, on other arches (e.g. arm), it won't flush the per CPU cache correctly. The atomics for arm _will_ do correct acquire/release memory model semantics. So, in the lock acquire, `while(myTicket!=nowServing)` --> `while (myTicket != atomic_load(&nowServing))`. In the release, `++nowServing;` --> `atomic_fetch_add(&nowServing,1);`

Comment: The reason is that, under arm, in addition to load exclusive/store exclusive asm instructions, the atomic functions will use the arm `dmb` instruction to do a memory barrier that forces the updated data to the other cores.